# Is there any R function for finding index of days of week, e.g., 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, & so on?

Tags: r, lubridate, dayofweek

Two columns [say col1 and col5] of my data frame are containing days of the week such as Sunday, Monday, ....

**I want** to convert those columns to their respective indices such as **'1' for 'Sunday, '2' for 'Monday', ... & so on**.
Currently, I'm using ifelse but I believe there might be **an efficient way to do the same in R**.

Sample code:

```
df$col1 = ifelse(df$col1=="Sunday",1,df$col1)
df$col1 = ifelse(df$col1=="Monday",2,df$col1)
....
df$col1 = ifelse(df$col1=="Saturday",7,df$col1)
```

And similar code for col5

```
df$col5 = ifelse(df$col5=="Sunday",1,df$col5)
df$col5 = ifelse(df$col5=="Monday",2,df$col5)
....
df$col5 = ifelse(df$col5=="Saturday",7,df$col5)
```

I tried looking for suitable function in lubridate package but couldn't find any.

Comment: Can you be more specific with the output you want and an example of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use match:

```
dow <- c('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday')
df$col1 <- match(df$col1, dow)
```

Comment: Thanks. This simplest solution saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler than match is what we could call "lookup table", or here simply a named vector:

```
R> dow <- 1:7 
R> names(dow) <- c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
                   "Thursday",  "Friday", "Saturday")
R> dow["Thursday"]
Thursday
       5
R> unname(dow["Thursday"])    # if you want to drop the name
[1] 5
R>
```

Programmatically you could do the same via a `switch` statement.

*Edit:*  As requested.

```
## switch
dow <- function(d) {
    switch(d,
    Sunday    = 1,
    Monday    = 2,
    Tuesday   = 3,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday  = 5,
    Friday    = 6,
    Saturday  = 7)
```

Example use

```
R> dow("Monday")
[1] 2
R> dow("Friday")
[1] 6
R> 
}
```

Comment: This is seems like the best solution. In case it isn't clear `dow[df$col1]` would produce your column vector.

Comment: @Dirk, earlier I had tried switch but honestly speaking didn't put enough effort to get the desired output. Can you give a sample code for the same?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks for the solution. Such tips saves a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

You could use lubridate to do this:

```
lubridate::wday(lubridate::today(),
                week_start = 1,
                label = TRUE)
[1] Fr
Levels: Mo < Di < Mi < Do < Fr < Sa < So
```

Comment: The OP hasn't given a clear desired output, but it seems like they want the number of the day of the week, not its abbreviation

Comment: There is also an option to set this: as.integer(lubridate::wday(lubridate::today(),
                week_start = 1,
                abbr = FALSE,
                locale = "English",
                label = TRUE))

Comment: abbr = FALSE is the parameter for the full name

Comment: @Florian; wday() from lubridate was the first function in my mind. I also tried as.numeric(wday(df$col1) and as.integer(wday(df$col1) but it didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the levels of a factor sets the numbers as.numeric returns.

```
df= data.frame(col1 = c("Friday", "Monday", "Wednesday"), col5 = c("Tuesday", "Saturday", "Monday"))
df$col1 = factor(df$col1, levels=c("Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
df$col1 = as.numeric(df$col1)
df$col5 = factor(df$col5, levels=c("Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
df$col5 = as.numeric(df$col5)
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution is simple. however, I might need to change the order of factors

Comment: The order is completely based on the order of the vector passed as levels. It is trivial to change.